# Excel VBA formatting Hexadecimal

Tags: vba, excel, hex

I want to convert hexadecimal which are 3 digits long into 6 digits. For example 12F shd be 00012F. I tried this code but it didnt work.

```
endadd = Format(endadd, "000000")
```

Comment: Try `endadd = Right("000000" & endadd,6)`

Comment: Thanks it works like a charm. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Scott Craner pointed out, a simple `Right("000000" & endadd,6)` will work perfectly well, but `Right$("000000" & endadd,6)` is slightly faster.

Furthermore, from a performance perspective, it really depends on whether the original source of the `endadd` value is a String or Numeric.

```
'CONCAT String Approach
'If the hex source is a string, then this is the most efficient approach
formattedHex = Right$("000000" & "12F", 2)

'CONCAT Numeric Approach
'But if the hex source is a numeric, then this hex conversion AND concatenation is required, but it is SLOW
formattedHex = Right$("000000" & Hex$(&H12F), 2)

'ADDITION/OR Numeric Approach
'When the hex source is numeric it is more efficient to use a bit trick to add AND convert
formattedHex = Right$(Hex$(&H1000000 + &H12F), 2)
formattedHex = Right$(Hex$(&H1000000 Or &H12F), 2)
```

Results from a 10m operation loop:

```
Approach                  | Using Right | Using Right$ |
==========================+=============================
CONCAT String Approach    | 1.59s       | 1.40s
CONCAT Numeric Approach   | 2.63s       | 2.33s
ADDITION Numeric Approach | 1.74s       | 1.60s
======================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement following function

```
    Public Function HexByte2Char(ByVal Value As Byte) As String
      ' Return a byte value as a two-digit hex string.
      HexByte2Char = IIf(Value < &H10, "0", "") & Hex$(Value)
    End Function

Usage
Dim s As String
s = HexByte2Char(dec_number)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When posting answers with code, please explain how your code solves the OP's problem :)